# Implement python-firebase in android

Tags: android, python-2.7, firebase, kivy, buildozer

I have python 2.7.6, the newest kivy and buildozer installed. 
Now I want to use firebase for python, downloaded by: `sudo pip install python-firebase`.

I can add this to the requirements in the buildozer.spec file as python-firebase. This all works fine and in the folder .buildozer/applibs/ I got:

firebase,
python_firebase-1.2.dist-info,
requests,
requests-2.9.1.dist-info.

So I expect that I could import firebase in my application, but that doesn't work. when I add: `from firebase import firebase` the app on android can not even run (I see the kivy app logo, but then the app shuts down).

Can anyone explain me why and what the next steps are?

edit 1: 
`I/python  (14201):    File "/home/notwaka/Desktop/App/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/firebase/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
I/python  (14201):    File "/home/notwaka/Desktop/App/.buildozer/android/app/_applibs/firebase/async.py", line 1, in <module>
I/python  (14201):    File "/home/notwaka/Desktop/App/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
I/python  (14201):  ImportError: No module named _multiprocessing
I/python  (14201): Python for android ended.`

Comment: What doesn't work and what the errors are?

Comment: When I use: `buildozer android debug deploy run' the app closes. And it does that because I add : from firebase import firebase. I don't see any error.

Comment: Errors are available in logcat. This is standard Android development knowledge.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but why are you using Python to talk to Firebase when there is an [Android SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/) available too?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I do everything in python, so I want to store some variables from my python script to firebase. 

I found an error and I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `multiprocessing` module is not supported in Android due to incompatibilities with bionic (Android's libc). I would suggest trying to use the Firebase Android SDK via pyjnius, or just make web requests using Kivy's `UrlRequest` or via Twisted - it's just a REST API, after all.

Comment: okey, thanks!~Could you also explain me how to run the non-async methods in a thread? Because I only want to use it, then I need to edit the code.

Comment: Actually, looking more at the firebase code, that isn't possible. It automatically imports multiprocessing, whether you will use it or not. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I solved it now with using the requests python lib. It was actually quite simple, now I don't need any firebase lib. Thanks! @Ryan-P

Comment: @TimNagelkerke The reason I suggested using UrlRequest or Twisted rather than requests is because requests blocks while the others do not. If you use requests in the main thread, your app will pause while it waits for a response. If the site is not responding or otherwise inaccessible, your app will likely produce an ANR (Application Not Responding) crash.

Comment: Did you end up getting to run the Firebase Modules like Push notification or Analytics ?